# Included class inside a PHPUnit file can't use Autoloader?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, autoload

I have write a `router.test.php` file:

```
class RouterTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        require_once '../router.class.php';
    }


    public function testUnit()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

... for simply test if my PHPUnit library is working correctly. But when I type `phpunit router.test.php` in my console I get this error message: `Fatal error: Trait 'Core' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\_Framework\ver_3\libraries\router\router.class.php on line 23`

... my Router class is working correctly and my Autoloader automatically include trait (named Core) inside my Router class.

*Where is the problem?*

My Autoloader register method looks like:

```
public static function register()
{
    return spl_autoload_register(
        __CLASS__ . '::load'
    );
}
```

... I use this method in my index.php file, should I write another autoloader for PHPUnits?

---

I have include necessary files in the setUp method, now the class looks like that:

```
<?php
use Framework\Libraries\Configuration\Configuration;
use Framework\Libraries\Autoload\Autoloader;



class RouterTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        require '../../core.trait.php';
        require '../../configuration/configuration.class.php';
        require '../../autoload/autoloader.class.php';

        Configuration::set('files', [
            require '../../../configuration/framework.configuration.php',
            require '../../../configuration/autoloader.configuration.php',
            require '../../../configuration/router.configuration.php',
        ]);

        Autoloader::set('prefixes', ['Framework']);
        Autoloader::set('extensions', ['.class.php', '.trait.php']);
        Autoloader::register();

        require_once '../router.class.php';
    }

    public function testUnit()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

... an I get a new error message: `E Time: 109 ms, Memory: 1.75Mb There was 1 error`, but I can't get the error message. I think it's because Autoloader can't load files because of wrong path.

Comment: You need to include your autoloader class in this class too. `include_once('AutoLoader.php');` or you can create `bootstrap.php` file for phpunit & include your all required class in that file.

Comment: @Rikesh Thanks you, It seems it works. You can post a reply so I approved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't load index file automatically. So you need to include all your relevant class in your unit test class by adding `include_once('AutoLoader.php');` in or another way is to create a `bootstrap.php` file & include all classes you need in all the PHPUnit Test class.

[*Reference*](http://jes.st/2011/phpunit-bootstrap-and-autoloading-classes/).